# Extent reports are not generated for Selenium cucumber

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java, extentreports

This is my first time using Selenium Cucumber, so I have tried integrating extent reports, but it wont generate. Please help!

I found that there are 2 ways, first is by adding property file and second is by adding it in code

1st way, issue is that there is no main/resources in my project, so I kept a extent.properties in resources folder, but I am guessing it wont read the file as it is not in classpath
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/950V8.png)

So, I tried adding it directly in the stepDef package baseclass.

But the extent reports are not generated. I could probably try generating it with other dependencies, but I want to know what I am doing wrong here in either of the methods as mentioned above. Any help is very much appreciated.

I have the code maintained in my Github profile, so you can have a better look there if you want
https://github.com/KrisDeluca/DemoWebShop

Here is my POM file snippet
[POM.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE8J8.png)

Here is my Extent.properties

[Extent.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUb9k.png)

Here is my code snippet added to the baseclass for Step definitions

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQKo1.png)

Comment: I am really sorry for not pasting the code itself rather than pics, as this is my first post I just couldn't get past the error asking to indent the code